# While loop with assignment operator

Tags: php, while-loop, operators

I can't seem to figure out how this loop works in PHP:

```
$people = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    $people[] = $row;
```

It seems as though the loop would just keep going, infinitely. But, it doesn't How exactly does this work? Can someone explain it to me step-by-step? I'm guessing that the while loop could also be written like this:

```
while(($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) == true)
```

Comment: Don't you need to specify a row name: `$row = fetch_assoc()['my_row']`

Comment: @735Tesla normally I would, but I don't in this occasion, I need all of the rows written to an array.

Comment: so the variable `$row` is not actually referring to an individual row?

Comment: fetch_assoc returns NULL once it reaches end of data set. So no it is not an infinite loop.

Comment: @Hameed about `isset()` to check if there is still data?

Comment: @Hameed `fetch_assoc()` should never return NULL. `NULL != FALSE` as well so none of our loops would work if that was true. It should return false at the end of a data set.

Comment: @735Tesla `fetch_*` functions are suffecient. Using `isset` would be redundant.

Comment: @MikeShi That is what [PHP documentation](http://au2.php.net/mysqli_fetch_assoc) says.. It is ironic because their description differs between mysql and mysqli. You are right about NULL not being the same as false, but I just tested a while loop with NULL and it worked. I guess it depends on the language implementation.

Comment: @Hameed sorry I haven't been getting enough sleep lately. I was thinking about PDO but then I just realized PDO uses fetch() not fetch_assoc(). I thought something was off... Thank you for the correction.

Comment: It is ok. It happens to all of us. Only this morning I moved a wrong script to production. [*_*] and I only realized when users started calling...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fetch_assoc fetches one result row at a time and stores it in $row. Since this is in a loop, you are fetching until you run out of rows

In the loop you are essentially pushing the $row value into a $people array

Answer (score 1):

[`fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) will return false either upon an error or when the cursor for the fetch hits the end of all the rows and no more rows can be fetched, so it will return false.

Every time you fetch for the query, a cursor keeps track of the last returned row and will continue to keep track ultimately till you finish reading all rows.

**Edit:** Sorry I was thinking about PDO and not mysqli, however it should be about the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
$people = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
   $people[] = $row;
```

Example how its works  (`MySQL`):

```
$people = array();
$result = mysql_query($query);
$rows_count = mysql_num_rows($result);
for ($i = $rows_count - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
   mysql_data_seek($result, $i);
   $people[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
}
```

How U see first option is more compact.